# How do I implement an interface on a form with multiple of the same control?

Tags: c#, events, button, interface

Ok so I have built a custom control that handles wysiwyg editing. Essentially on 1 control I have multiple instances of my wysiwyg editor. So one might be for editing, let's say, a recipe. Another might be for notes for that recipe.

I have a button on my wysiwyg editor that uses an interface to do callbacks to the control that holds them both, so I know on my parent control when the button was clicked. How do I find out which control fired the callback?

Example

**Main Form**

```
public partial class MyCustomControl: RecipeControl.ISavedButton {

    private void SaveButton_Clicked(){
        //Do Work but how do I find out which control fired this event?
        //Was it RecipeControl1 or RecipeControl2
    }

}
```

**My Solution**

On my recipe control I did this.

```
private void RecipeSaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (RecipeSaveButtonListener != null) {
        RecipeSaveButtonListener.RecipeSaveButton_Clicked(this, EventArgs.Empty); //This referring to the control, not the button.
    }
}
```

On my main control I did this.

```
private void RecipeSaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (sender == RecipeControl1){ 

    } else if (sender == RecipeControl2) { 

    }
}
```

I have implemented both answers and both are very very good. Sorry I can't accept both of them.

Comment: there is not any `bult-in` way, you should implement it by yourself.

Comment: Why does the calling control need to know that?  My gut instinct is that whatever the caller is doing should in fact be done by the control itself.

Comment: Well its a 1 to many relationship. The control can perform many different functions being a wysiwyg editor and might need to implement different behaviors depending on what type of view it sits in. So for example, I want a user to be associated with the notes implementation, but I dont want to add a User object to the control itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most event handlers (like a button click) are built with a standard interface to tell you who performed the action.  Take a modified version of your "event handler" for the `RecipeControl's` Button Click event:

```
 private void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //Do Work but how do I find out which control fired this event?
        RecipeControl ctl = sender as RecipeControl;
    }
```

So when a button is clicked in your `RecipeControl`, it should fire an event something like:

```
this.SaveButtonClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

By design, all the event Handlers receive two parameters:

- object sender: refers to the object that raised the event
- EventArgs e: EventArgs or a specialized class derived from EventArgs, depending on the event type

Usually, a different event handler is attached to a single control, so that you don't worry about sender. But, in your case, it seems that you are using the same handler for all your controls. In this case you have to make different things depending on the sender.

To do so, you need to check if the sender is the one you're interested in, like this (I'm supposing the button name is Button1)

```
public ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender== RecipeControl1.Button1)
    {
    }
    else if (sender == RecipeControl2.Button1)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this not just be my button that sits on the control instead of the control? Example, I can't cast the sender to the control if the button is the one that fired it. Also, shouldn't that be sender not object.

Comment: Sorry, since Steve had the correct firing for the `sender` `this` I have awarded him the answer. However, I did upvote yours since it is also very good. I see, I didn't know you could implement it like that either.

Comment: Don't worry. This isn't a question of winners and losers! ;) And thanks for your comment that allowed me to modify my answer.